# Django foo_set doesnt work

Tags: python, django, django-models

I got stucked with Django (v1.9.4) a bit. I have created two models, Foo and 
Bar:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
class Bar(models.Model):
    foo_id = models.ForeignKey(Foo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

migrate it (sqlite3) and few moments later realized that it should be

> foo instead of foo_id:

```
foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I migrated it again, with foo this time, but even after this correction I wasn't able to use

```
f = Foo.objects.filter(pk=1) 
f.bar_set.all()
```

Is there a way to deal with this?

Edit.
Error msg:
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:'Foo' object has no attribute 'bar_set'

Comment: Edited my question, tnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not working because `filter` returns  a `QuerySet` (which is a list), not an object. You need to use `get` instead of `filter` because `get` returns an object.

```
f = Foo.objects.get(pk=1)
f.bar_set.all()
```